# The command status stop "Creating job WordCountTopology" after submit a Topology

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper, mesos, apache-storm-topology, apache-aurora

I attempted to build a Heron Cluster using Apache Mesos, Apache Aurora, ZooKeeper and HDFS. However, When I submit the WordCountTopology after finished it, the command ouput as following: Stopping the "Creating job WordCountTopology".

```
yitian@ubuntu:~/.heron/conf/aurora$ heron submit aurora/yitian/devel --config-path ~/.heron/conf ~/.heron/examples/heron-api-examples.jar com.twitter.heron.examples.api.WordCountTopology WordCountTopology
[2018-02-13 06:58:30 +0000] [INFO]: Using cluster definition in /home/yitian/.heron/conf/aurora
[2018-02-13 06:58:30 +0000] [INFO]: Launching topology: 'WordCountTopology'
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/yitian/.heron/lib/uploader/heron-dlog-uploader.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/yitian/.heron/lib/statemgr/heron-zookeeper-statemgr.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.JDK14LoggerFactory]
[2018-02-13 06:58:31 -0800] [INFO] com.twitter.heron.statemgr.zookeeper.curator.CuratorStateManager: Starting Curator client connecting to: heron01:2181  
[2018-02-13 06:58:31 -0800] [INFO] org.apache.curator.framework.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl: Starting  
[2018-02-13 06:58:31 -0800] [INFO] org.apache.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager: State change: CONNECTED  
[2018-02-13 06:58:31 -0800] [INFO] com.twitter.heron.statemgr.zookeeper.curator.CuratorStateManager: Directory tree initialized.  
[2018-02-13 06:58:31 -0800] [INFO] com.twitter.heron.statemgr.zookeeper.curator.CuratorStateManager: Checking existence of path: /home/yitian/heron/state/topologies/WordCountTopology  
[2018-02-13 06:58:34 -0800] [INFO] com.twitter.heron.uploader.hdfs.HdfsUploader: The destination directory does not exist. Creating it now at URI '/home/yitian/heron/topologies/aurora'  
[2018-02-13 06:58:37 -0800] [INFO] com.twitter.heron.uploader.hdfs.HdfsUploader: Uploading topology package at '/tmp/tmpvYzRv7/topology.tar.gz' to target HDFS at '/home/yitian/heron/topologies/aurora/WordCountTopology-yitian-tag-0--8268125700662472072.tar.gz'  
[2018-02-13 06:58:41 -0800] [INFO] com.twitter.heron.statemgr.zookeeper.curator.CuratorStateManager: Created node for path: /home/yitian/heron/state/topologies/WordCountTopology  
[2018-02-13 06:58:41 -0800] [INFO] com.twitter.heron.statemgr.zookeeper.curator.CuratorStateManager: Created node for path: /home/yitian/heron/state/packingplans/WordCountTopology  
[2018-02-13 06:58:41 -0800] [INFO] com.twitter.heron.statemgr.zookeeper.curator.CuratorStateManager: Created node for path: /home/yitian/heron/state/executionstate/WordCountTopology  
[2018-02-13 06:58:41 -0800] [INFO] com.twitter.heron.scheduler.aurora.AuroraLauncher: Launching topology in aurora  
[2018-02-13 06:58:41 -0800] [INFO] com.twitter.heron.scheduler.utils.SchedulerUtils: Updating scheduled-resource in packing plan: WordCountTopology  
[2018-02-13 06:58:41 -0800] [INFO] com.twitter.heron.statemgr.zookeeper.curator.CuratorStateManager: Deleted node for path: /home/yitian/heron/state/packingplans/WordCountTopology  
[2018-02-13 06:58:41 -0800] [INFO] com.twitter.heron.statemgr.zookeeper.curator.CuratorStateManager: Created node for path: /home/yitian/heron/state/packingplans/WordCountTopology  
INFO] Creating job WordCountTopology
```

Heron Tracker shows:

```
status  "success"
executiontime   0.00007081031799316406
message ""
version "0.17.1"
result  {}
```

Heron UI shows nothing:
[image]

Aurora sheduler running as:
[image]

Besides, it has two host in the cluster.

1. The master named heron01, running Mesos Master, zookeeper and Aurora Scheduler.
2. The slave named heron02, running Mesos slave, Aurora Observer and Executor.

I can open the Observer(`heron02:1338`) and Executor(`heron02:5051`) using website. I do not know where I made a mistake. The cluster configuration so complex that I cannot show here totally. You can see my website about the cluster configuration. I apologies my website is Chinese language but I believe you can understand the configuration file content in the website. The blog is [here](http://www.zhangyitian.cn/blog/heron-%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8apache-auroramesos%E9%83%A8%E7%BD%B2heron%E9%9B%86%E7%BE%A4/)
Thanks for your help so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by insufficient cluster resources. When Aurora Scheduler scheduled the instances to worker node in Heron cluster, if a worker node does not have enough resources to allocate an instance, it will cause the instance to be pending, waiting for a working node with sufficient resources in the cluster to appear. 
So this problem was solved by increasing the RAM resources of worker node in the Heron cluster.